# Classes connected but don´t respond properly

Tags: python-2.7, class, methods, pyqt4

i´m trying to connect two methods which are in two different classes. In the class called "Ventana", which is my main window, i have this method:

```
def addChannel(self):
    global channelCount

    self.scrollLayout = QFormLayout()

    self.canal = QwtPlot()
    self.canal.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)

    if channelCount <= 4:                                
        self.splitter1.addWidget(self.canal)
        channelCount += 1
        print str(channelCount)
```

In another class, i have these methods:

```
class QwtPlotList(QDialog):
def __init__(self):
    QDialog.__init__(self)
    uic.loadUi("PropiedadesCanal.ui", self)
    self.botonAdd.clicked.connect(self.addChannel_2)

def addChannel_2(self):
    global channelCount
    self.botonAdd.clicked.connect(Ventana().addChannel)
    if channelCount <= 4:
        self.listWidget.addItem("Canal : " + str(channelCount))
```

What i´m trying to do is that, when i push the button "`botonAdd`", the "`addChannel_2`" method calls the "addChannel" method, which is in the `Ventana` class. Then, a `QWidget` ("self.canal") is created.

What happens with this code, it is that when i push the "`botonAdd`", it puts an item in the `listWidget` but it doesn´t create the `QWidget`. And if i create the "`QWidget`" with a button in a toolbar, it doesn´t add any item in the `QListWidget`

You can see all this in these images:

[The "botonAdd" creates an item in the QListWidget but not a QWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDc1E.jpg)

[Another button creates the Qwidget, but not the item in the QListWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7iHt.jpg)

Hope you can help me. Thanks for your time and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several issues

**1.** Calling a function in the class `Ventana` from another class. What you do:

```
    self.botonAdd.clicked.connect(Ventana().addChannel)
```

`Ventana()` creates a new instance of the class `Ventana`. The
    button `botonAdd` is not connected to your main window, it is
    connected to another main window you just created. This new window
    is not shown, and is destroyed add the end of `addChannel_2` by the
    garbage collector (because you don't keep a reference to it).

To call the right `addChannel`, you need a reference to your actual main window. In Qt, the main window is usually the parent of the other widget. You need to change the definition of `QwtPlotList` so that it can have a parent:

```
    class QwtPlotList(QDialog):
      def __init__(self,parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self,parent)

    #in main window Ventana
    self.myDialog=QwtPlotList(self)
```

Then you can call any method of `Ventana` in `QwtPlotList`:

```
    #in QwtPlotList
    self.parent().any_method()
```

**2.** Connecting button click to multitple functions. What you do:

```
    self.botonAdd.clicked.connect(self.function1)

    def function1(self):
      self.botonAdd.clicked.connect(function2)
```

Every time the button is click, `function1` will be called, and will connect the button click to another function. Those connections are additive. The first time you click the button, `function1` is called and the button is connect to `function2`. The second time, `function1` and `function2` are called, and the button is connect to `function2`. The third time, `function1`, `function2` and again `function2` are called, etc.

You need to simply call the `function2`, without connecting the button:

```
def function1:
  function2()
```

**3.** Using globals: you should avoid it, there's often a better solution.
  I understand you have two functions that need to use the same variable `channelCount`. To avoid global, I would keep a reference to `channelCount` in `QwtPlotList`, and pass it as a parameter in `addChannel`

```
def addChannel(channelCount):
  channelCount+=1
  return channelCount

#QWtPlotList 
  #init
    self.channelCount=3  

  def addChannel_2(self):
    self.channelCount=addChannel(self.channelCount)
```

I let you figure out how to put everything together :)

Comment: Hi!, thank you so much for your answer, i learned new things with it. But i continue having troubles. Now i get an error that says: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'channelCount' referenced before assignment" and it still doesn´t work if i solve, in a simple way, that error. I edited the question and i put what i´ve done with your answers. Sorry if i can´t get it.

Comment: Don't edit your question. If you have a new issue that you can't fixed, post a new question.